# Laravel Logout Routes Redirects But Login Persists

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and this is my logout route:

```
Route::get('/logout', [ 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout', 'as' => 'logout']);
```

When I navigate to `/logout` I get the redirect back to the homepage, but I don't get logged out. When I try to go to a protected route, like so:

```
Route::get('/amIloggedout',['middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'MomsController@firstPass',
    'as'   => 'moms.Logout'
]);
```

It lets me right in and the view generated by that controller is also passing information that is telling me I am logged in (displaying my username).

That controller is here, I don't think I am inadvertently logging myself back in automatically:

```
public function firstPass()
{
if(Auth::user()->Type=="Employee" || Auth::user()->Type=="ADMIN")
{
//retrieve data or else echo ACCESS DENIED below
```

So I don't understand why it isn't working? Maybe because I am logging in using usernames instead of emails? But I looked at the `@getLogout` function it doesn't seem to care how you login, it's all about logging out.

```
public function getLogout()
    {
        return $this->logout();
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->logout();

        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
    }
```

So what am I doing wrong? The logout has always worked fine in my other apps so I'm wondering what I have inadvertently done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the logout route to:

`Route::get('/logout', [ 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@logout', 'as' => 'logout']);`

Made it work, but I really don't understand why `@getLogout` doesn't work if it calls `@logout` anyway? Oh well, glad to have it working. :)